# adding audio to video without knowing length of either

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to replace the audio in the video, but I do not know the duration of the video. I only know the duration of the audio sometimes, not always. The duration of video is not known.

What ffmpeg command should I use so that audio gets repeated to full length of video if video is longer?

But if video is shorter than audio, then either video can be repeated or audio can be cut short, either is ok.

Is it possible to achieve that using a single command, without worrying about durations, not having to change commands depending on audio/video lengths?

Currently I know this command below, but in this case the longer video gets cut short. I don't want that.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: "without knowing length of either" -> " I only know the duration of the audio." - which one is it? Please correct.

Comment: Hi, I meant that sometimes I might know the length of audio. Title of question can be, without knowing length of video. Thanks

Comment: as variant `ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -stream_loop -1 -i "audio.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy -shortest out.mp4`